# PHP ip request -- repeat every 5 seconds with the date in the output

Tags: scripting, date, php, ip-address

I have a code in php and it shows ip adress. But it works only for once when I enter. So I want to use this code to works in every 5 second.

```
your ip : 5.4.3.2.1 ; 18:05
your ip : 5.4.3.2.1 ; 18:10
```

like this. Can someone help me to solve this ?

```
<?php

    // Pull contents from ip6.me
$file = file_get_contents('http://ip6.me/');

// Trim IP based on HTML formatting
$pos = strpos( $file, '+3' ) + 3;
$ip = substr( $file, $pos, strlen( $file ) );

// Trim IP based on HTML formatting
$pos = strpos( $ip, '</' );
$ip = substr( $ip, 0, $pos );

// Output the IP address of your box
echo "My IP address ; $ip";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an existing script every 5 seconds, displaying its output with the current date in hours & minutes, this would do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

while :
do
  printf '%s ; %s\n' "$(./myip.py)" $(date +%H:%M)
  sleep 5
done
```

Hit Control-C to end the infinite loop. Besides the infinite loop and the "wait 5 seconds between each iteration", the `printf` statement takes the output of the script (here I named it `myip.py`) and appends a semicolon and the output of `date +%H:%M` to it.